# JMSTemplate doesn't receive the String I sent right before?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I have a JMSTemplate jmsT. To test it out, my only two lines of code are:

```
jmsT.convertAndSend("Location", "Message");
jmsT.receiveAndConvert("Location");
```

The code stalls at receiveAndConvert, waiting forever to receive a message as if it doesn't exist, despite that being exactly what the previous line creates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an embedded ActiveMQ, you must use a `CachingConnectionFactory`. Otherwise the embedded broker will go away between the two calls.

DEBUG logging is always your friend.

Comment: Would that also work if I had the convertAndSend and receiveAndConvert in different applications?

Comment: It's unusual to use an embedded broker to communicate between applications; you would normally have an external broker running. You can use an embedded broker but it would need to listen on a `tcp` transport instead of the `vm` transport. It's always a good idea to use a `CachingConnectionFactory` with a `JmsTemplate` for performance reasons.